# Corona Sdk: Putting Items Created by a Function in a Table

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I can't figure out how to put the objects created by a simple function in a table, to have them figure as individual identities..

E.g.

```
local function spawncibo()
nuovoCibo = display.newImage("immagini/cibo/cibo001.png")
end
timer.performWithDelay(1500, spawncibo, -1)
```

I tried to do it with a for loop, but it doesn't work (if i try to print the table I always get a nil result).

Any suggestion would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Providing I have correctly understood your question, you may try something like this :

```
local cibo = {}
local function spawncibo()
  cibo[#cibo+1] = display.newImage(string.format(
    "immagini/cibo/cibo%3d.png", #cibo+1))
end
timer.performWithDelay(1500, spawncibo, -1)
```

This will read files `cibo001.png`, `cibo002.png`, ... every 1.5 s and put all images into the `cibo` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
local spawnedCibos = {}
local function spawncibo()
    nuovoCibo = display.newImage("immagini/cibo/cibo001.png")
    table.insert(spawnedCibos, nuovoCibo);
end
timer.performWithDelay(1500, spawncibo, -1);

local function enterFrameListener( event )
    for index=#spawnedCibos, 1, -1 do
        local cibo = spawnedCibos[index];
        cibo.x = cibo.x + 1;
        if cibo.x > display.contentWidth then
            cibo:removeSelf();
            table.remove(spawnedCibos, index);
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
local spawned = {} -- local table to hold all the spawned images
local timerHandle = nil -- local handle for the timer. It can later be used to cancel it if you want to

local function spawnCibo()
    local nuovoCibo = display.newImage('immagini/cibo/cibo001.png')
    table.insert(spawned, nuovoCibo) -- insert the new DisplayObject (neovoCibo) at the end of the spawned table.
end

local function frameListener()
    for k, v in pairs(spawned) do -- iterate through all key, value pairs in the table
        if (conditions) then -- you will probably want to change conditions to some sort of method to determine if you want to delete the cibo
            display.remove(spawned[k]) -- remove the part of the object that gets rendered
            spawned[k] = nil -- remove the reference to the object in the table, freeing it up for garbage collection
        end
    end
end

timer.performWithDelay(1500, spawnCibo, 0) -- call spawnCibo() every 1.5 seconds, forever (That's what the 0 is for) or until timer.cancel is called on timerHandle
Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', frameListener) --
```

If you've got any other questions, feel free to ask.